# Issue with a Styling based Userscript

Tags: javascript, css

let me start off by saying that I virtually know nothing about what I'm doing, other than wanting to finally finish this simple script. I believe I know the limitations of this simple script, I just can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working as it's intended. I have tried to use features of similar CSS injecting scripts and have unfortunately failed in having the styling applied correctly.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Test1
// @namespace       +mK or OMGWTFISTHIS
// @description     Changes HackForums to a dark, sleek theme!
// @include         http://www.hackforums.net/*
// @include         http://hackforums.net/*
// @version         1.3
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('.thead {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/SRMEIpU.png) repeat scroll right top #111111; height: 20px; !important}');
addGlobalStyle('.tcat {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/SRMEIpU.png) repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.tborder {background: #111111; border: 1px solid #1D1D1D; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.bitButton {background-color: #1E1E1E; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #505050 inset !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('#panel {border: 1px solid #111111; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.menu ul, .tfoot  {background: #111111 !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.pm_alert {border: 1px solid #0AFF00 !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('body {background: #072948 url(http://imgur.com/dY3iaZ2.png) fixed; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.bottommenu {background: #111111; border: 1px solid #000000; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.button {background-color: #1E1E1E; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #505050 inset !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.shadetabs li a, .shadetabs li a.selected {background-color: #1E1E1E; color: #6D6D6D; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #505050 inset !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.shadetabs li a.selected, .shadetabs li a:hover {background-color: #111111; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #505050 inset !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.subforumicon.ajax_mark_read {background: #072948 url(http://i.imgur.com/Wfru130.gif) fixed; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('a:hover, a:active, .menu ul a:hover, .menu ul a:active {color: #cccccc; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.shadetabs li a:hover {color: #fff; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.shadetabs li a.selected {color: #fff; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.pagination_current {background: #383737 !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.pagination a, .pagination a:hover {background-color: #181818; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.navButton:hover {border-top: 1px solid #919191; background: #333333; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.tcat a:hover, .tcat a:active, .tfoot a:hover, .tfoot a:active, .navigation a:hover, .navigation a:active {color: #949494; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.pagination a:hover {color: #949494; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('textarea, input.textbox {border: 1px solid #000000; !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('.subject_new, a.subject_new {font-weight: bold; !important;');
```

This is my issue:

When you come to the website, it looks great, right? Everything is supposed to be a dark variant of the default theme. If I navigate to ANY link within the page, all the styling will be applied correctly. If I REFRESH (F5) the current, active page, the styling will literally install half of styling. It only does this while @run-at document-start is currently active. If I remove that line completely, the page will obviously flash due to the script executing after the DOM has loaded, but the styling will be applied correctly.

It seems that when I try to fix one issue (flashing), another issue (not applying all styles) becomes present.

Do you have any suggestions? I'm fresh out of ideas, and even went as far as removing all image styles, thinking that was the root cause of it. Nope.

Comment: why you dont generate an CSS-File and load it on the header with **<link>** Tag? Your script take down the rendering process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it, but unfortunately, the issue still resides. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the following will only call `addGlobalStyle` once which will result in cleaner markup and might clear up the behavior you were seeing:

```
var styles = [];

styles.push('.thead {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/SRMEIpU.png) repeat scroll right top #111111; height: 20px; !important}');
styles.push('.tcat {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/SRMEIpU.png) repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }');
//lines removed, re-add others in provided code

addGlobalStyle(styles.join(''));
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JasonAller/j5mPS/)

This is because `addGlobalStyle` was adding a separate `<style>` tag containing the content it was called with each time it was called. This way we collect the changes you want to make and only call it once resulting in only one `<style>` tag with all the content being added.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I appreciate it. I tried applying it that way, but once again, it did not work as intended. The styles applied nicely when I was going to a new link each time, but as soon as I refreshed the current page, half the styling applies. :\ I wish I could somehow analyze the website. Could it be because the content on the page loads too fast? I tried using an alert yesterday, and when I refreshed, the alert would load after the content has been loaded. If I went to a new link, the alert would be BEFORE the content loaded.

Comment: Is it a static html file? Where is the JavaScript being loaded on the page, in the head, with on page load, at the bottom?

Comment: It appears to be static, but it's in .PHP.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter and can't edit it: It appears to be static, but it's in .PHP. Just looked at it, and half of the Javascript is loaded in the head, and the other half is loaded at the bottom. I'm guessing the heavier JS files are loaded at the bottom, but I'm not sure. I must say, last night, I tried using Userstyle's way of applying styles, and it worked great (the example script I had). But as soon as I replace their irrelevant styles for a different website and finish it up for the one I need it for, it breaks on page refresh. >.> I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: when you refresh and it isn't right, can you use your browser's inspect element mode to see what the content of the `<style>` element in the `<head>` looks like?

Comment: If I used my original example of the script, it applied a <style> element for each and every item I was a styling, which was a bit annoying. I did notice though, that the elements in which were NOT loading due to the page refresh, were simply not present. Almost as if it just skipped over them. Perhaps due to speed? Anyways, with your change, it applied it all to one element, which is great. But unfortunately, .thead among other items are not styled, even though they're present within the CSS element. http://puu.sh/7wyXv/8e6615f6c9.png

Comment: I don't know if this helps you at all, but I deleted the Global and Tabbed CSS (Just the entire default CSS file) nodes from Inspect Element out of curiosity, and to my surprise, .thead and .tcat were both styled. Which is weird, because when I just press the refresh button to make the script 'break', it doesn't apply the styling.